# Import an External SQLite database to my project

Tags: qt, sqlite, qml

I'm interested in importing an external SQLite database to my project.
When using the QT Quick Local Storage:

`LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("QQmlExampleDB", "1.0", "The Example QML SQL!", 1000000);`

The problem is that, the program generates a NEW database, and if it's possible I'm interested in open an existing database.

Any idea?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all of you, with the information you have got me I could solve my problem, all the things I have had to do are:
First of all in main.cpp I set my offline Storage Path:

```
engine.setOfflineStoragePath(QString("./"));
```

Then I also add this code:

```
QDir dir("./Databases");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkpath(".");
}
QString new_name = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(("nameofthecopiedDB"),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());

QFile file(":/SQLite/nameofsourceDB.sqlite");
file.copy("./Databases/" + new_name + ".sqlite");
file.close();
```

Since I have the DB I would to use in my project in SQLite folder from my resources (:, indicates resources).

And then, in QML file, the openDatabaseSync() function:

```
 basedades = Sql.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync('nameofthecopiedDB',"1.0","Els meus entrenaments",1000000,"QSQLITE")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`openDatabaseSync` searches or creates dbs in the directory used for storing offline data.
That directory is identified by the data member `offlineStoragePath` of the `QQmlEngine` class.
To change it, you can use the the member method `setOfflineStoragePath` (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#offlineStoragePath-prop) for further details).
The first argument for `openDatabaseSync` is:

> The name of the database passed to openDatabase()

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html) for further details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is it possible that the current function openDatabaseSync doesn't work properly?
Because when I do it, no matter wich name I put on the openDataBaseSync, the program always creates a new db with a ranom name, for example:

a32d695d324fbf044d62821c5ee7e4de.sqlite

Thanks

Comment: As I remember the path to a database is `QQmlEngine::offlineStoragePafh` + md5(name) + ".sqlite". Where `name` is 1st parameter of `openDatabaseSync` so you just should put there your database with properly name and it will work.

Comment: @folibis It's enough to create the empty one with the right name, than swap the two files. Right?